# Pass result of click.command to another function

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-click

I am trying to implement basic command line functionality.

So I need to be able to pass file as argument, read it and pass result further.

But for some reason it doesn't work as expected.

```
import click


@click.command()
@click.argument('arg', nargs=1, type=click.File('r'))
def touch(arg):
    return len(arg.readlines())


def fill():
    print touch()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fill()
```

There is no any output.
But seems `touch()` is executing since in case if I am adding print statement into `touch()` I can see some stuff in output.

Comment: How can you execute `touch()` with no arguments if in you definition there is one required?

Comment: @Ilja `click` handles that under the hood

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, using click makes it such that your function never returns any value. you can use `click.echo` to print the values to the front-end, but you cannot return any values as it exits when function execution is finished. In other words, it no longer behaves as a function once you wrap it with click.command but instead becomes a command line program.

You can alternatively use `optparse` to achieve what you are trying to achieve.

Resources - https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html

Edit:- I found a similar question here, you can also use this as reference - [How do I return a value when @click.option is used to pass a command line argument to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246824/how-do-i-return-a-value-when-click-option-is-used-to-pass-a-command-line-argume)